# VBA EXCEL/WORD - SAVE AS

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a really easy question, but here what I have
I have a load of code that works fine but then when it comes to saving the document I can only get it to save as a specific name, but I want it to save as "Visitors Diary Recruitment (something unique)" so that it doesn't overwrite the document each time I run it and instead creates a new document.

```
With wApp
    .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 (path)
    .ActiveWindow.Close
    .Quit

    Set wApp = Nothing
    Set wDoc = Nothing
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the document with a unique Id (there are many options for this - depending on your need):

- Random number
- Use a datetime stamp
- Use a Guid

Using a random number:

```
set uniqueName = Int(25 * Rnd()) + 1 //25 is the amount of random numbers you want
```

Using a DateTime:

```
set uniqueName = Format(Now(), "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")
```

Using a Guid - I havn't done this myself yet, although i'm certain there must be a way to generate one. ([This](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=21) might help)

Then change your SaveAs to this:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 ("C:\Users\colesa\Desktop\Recruitment Macros\Visitor Diary Recruitment" +uniqueName + ".doc")
```

Comment: To be extra paranoid, you can add a `Do`...`Loop` that checks to see if the filename you're trying to use already exists. If it does, you can generate a new output or, if you're using a timestamp (which is what I would do), either wait a second, or add a counter to the end of it.

Comment: Thanks alot, Worked!

Comment: @Samuel Cole That's great to hear, please don't forget to accept the answer, so others know what they could use.